# Automatic Process kill process problem

Tags: process, kill, mx-linux

I am using **MX linux** for a few days and I found a problematic behavior. **Suddenly** sevaral processes were **killed automatically**. For this, I had to face many problems. Is there any way to stop it? I don't want kill process automatically. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Buy more memory.

Comment: But is there no way to stop automatically process killing?I have 4 GB ram and no way to expand more memory in my laptop.

Comment: Use larger swap and enjoy the slowness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to stop it?

Unfortunately there isn't.

The rationale is as follows: once a system runs completely out of memory, it must freeze, because it cannot even run the simplest command - since that would require allocating memory. The [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory)-Killer is designed to prevent the system from becoming completely unusable in this way by killing (based on some [heuristics](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) - others may say at random) processes to free memory. That way, an administrator can at least try to get the system back to a usable state, hopefully without having to reboot. Completely disabling this feature is not implemented (see also [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791623/12231187)).

To alleviate the problem, you can try to

1. Use `top` or any similar system monitor to investigate which program starts eating up memory. If it is one you wrote yourself, you may have created errors in the memory management that you can try to track down using tools such as `valgrind`. If it is a third-party program, you can try to limit its resources (see answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44985/377345), for example) so that it at least doesn't affect your system in general.
2. Try to tweak the settings of the OOM killer, e.g. [overcommiting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/432171/377345), but note that this can have side effects.
3. Increase the swap space (see comment by Ipor Sircer), but note that this will make the system very slow.

If your hardware ultimately is not up to the task, you may well have to think about upgrading.